# Keydown event not being picked up by event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out why the following doesn't work.

I am setting a `keydown` event handler, and then triggering the event.  But the handler doesn't detect it.

If anyone can enlighten me!

```
function onKeyDown(event)
{
 alert('keydown');   
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown, false);

var keydown = jQuery.Event('keydown', {which:38, keyCode:38});

$(document).keydown();
$(document).trigger(keydown);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4bf3z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://api.jquery.com/trigger/, emphasis added:

> Any event handlers **attached with .on() or one of its shortcut methods**
>   are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. They can be fired
>   manually, however, with the .trigger() method. A call to .trigger()
>   executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event
>   were triggered naturally by the user.

So, it works as expected if you attach the handler with jQuery instead of pure javascript:

```
function onKeyDown(event)
{
  alert('keydown');   
}

$(document).on('keydown', onKeyDown);    //   <----

var keydown = jQuery.Event('keydown', {which:38, keyCode:38});

$(document).keydown();
$(document).trigger(keydown);
```

Comment: thanks.  I ended up using this solution and replacing vanilla javascript code.  The reason was because there were too many tweaks and workarounds needed to get event.keyCode set properly, and using jQuery was just the simpler solution.

Comment: @Vigrond: By the way, if you can dispatch an event to solve an actual problem, you should almost definitely just be calling the function instead.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery’s `trigger` [only triggers jQuery-attached events](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/4bf3z/1/). Triggering actual DOM events is trickier, and the keyboard events module is still a working draft:

```
var e = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvents');
e.initKeyboardEvent('keydown');
document.dispatchEvent(e);
```

The arguments to `initKeyboardEvent` are on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Firefox uses [`initKeyEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.initKeyEvent).

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/4bf3z/3/)